# Развертывание django сервера на windows

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, apache, сервер

Я новичок в сетевых технологиях, вот решил попробовать запустить сервер с django. Сам проект готов (система авторизации для игры), работает на rest framework. Все хорошо пашет через обычный manage.py runserver. Но для того чтобы могли подключиться другие, я так понимаю, нужен какой-нибудь веб сервер вроде apache или nginx. И что делать дальше? Большинство статей рассказывают как запустить проект на том же localhost. А как сделать так, чтобы мой созданный api был доступен по моему ip? 
P.S. Еще вопрос. Насколько я понимаю нужен статический ip. Но если запустить с не статическим и просто передать пользователем свой ip на данный момент времени, будет работать? Спасибо.

Comment: С нестатическим не будет, так как он гарантировано будет за провайдерским NAT'ом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev понял, спасибо

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev совсем необязательно, некоторые провайдеры дают динамический внешний ip, к нему можно прикрутить DynDNS и получить нормально работающий сайт (я таким в школьные годы баловался)

Comment: @andreymal крайне расточительно во времена нехватки IP-адресов.